# Automatically disable abbreviation expansion when pasting code in Vim

Tags: vim

In a terminal instance of Vim, how can I make abbreviation expansion be automatically disabled when I am pasting code?

**Note:** The keyword here is *automatically*, not manually via `:set paste`.

Comment: What action exactly do you mean by "pasting code"?  Pasting the contents of one of the Vim registers?  Or pasting from external X clipboard or X selection?

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way for Vim to distinguish whether an input
character was actually typed by the user or was generated for them by
the X Window System through the clipboard or selection buffers. That
is why there is the paste mode to manually switch Vim into the state
when all input is not interpreted as interactively typed.

Thus, you have two alternatives:

1. Paste from the `"*` or `"+` registers (that represent the clipboard
   and X selection, respectively), *if you are using GVim or your Vim is
   compiled with the `X11` feature (or, at least, with the
   `xterm_clipboard` one)*.
2. In case of Vim running in the terminal, you can manually
   synchronize one of the registers (for example, the unnamed one, `""`)
   with the clipboard or X selection. For instance, since I use Vim only
   in the terminal, I define the following mappings for myself:

   ```
    nmap <silent> <leader>y :call system('xclip', @")<cr>
    nmap <silent> <leader>p :call XClipRead()<cr>

    function! XClipRead()
        let s = system('xclip -o')
        if v:shell_error
            return
        endif
        call setreg('"', s)
    endfunction
   ```

   To paste the contents of the X selection buffer using these
   mappings, you need to type the leader key followed by `p`, and
   then an appropriate Vim paste command. If you agree to lose
   the opportunity of using different paste commands (such as
   `P`, `gp`, `]p`, etc), you can define a mapping that does both
   things:

   ```
    nmap <silent> <leader>P :call XClipRead()<cr>p
   ```

Comment: Terminal vim can be compiled with X11 clipboard registers support. I do not know any distribution where non-tiny console vim is compiled without it.

Comment: @ZyX Vim has two features related to clipboards support: `X11` and `xterm_clipboard`.  The former provides both X clipboard and selection buffer register, while the latter gives only XTerm clipboard support.  And there are many situations when these features are disabled (or its inappropriate to recompile Vim with them).  Regarding distributions, it's not rare situation at all.  For example, `vim` (not `gvim`) package in Arch Linux has Vim compiled without both `X11` and `xterm_clipboard`.